# How to create an object in runtime and save its reference name in a list

Tags: python

I have created a class called 'runtime' and I want to create several instances of this class in runtime

```
class runtime:
    products = []
    number_of_objects = 0
    max_objects = 10

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self.name)
        runtime.number_of_objects += 1

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def list_of_products(cls):
        for i in cls.products:
            print(i)

while (True):
    print("1 create")
    print("2 view")
    print("3 delete")

    operation = input("enter your choice:")

    if int(operation) == 1:
        nick_name = input("enter nickname of the product:")
        runtime.products.append(nick_name)
        nick_name = runtime(nick_name)

    elif int(operation) == 2:
        runtime.list_of_products()
        runtime.products[0].get_name()

    elif int(operation) == 3:
        pass

    else:
        print("choice unknown")
```

but however, during the view operation when I try to get the name of an instance that I have created I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runtime objects.py", line 34, in <module>
    eval(runtime.products[0]).get_name()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'object1' is not defined
```

when I omit the eval() function it returns AttributeError

Comment: In `runtime.products.append(nick_name)`, `nick_name` is a string, You need to create an instance: `runtime(nick_name)` first.
P.S. your code and traceback are from different versions.

Comment: Thanks man, by reading your comment I tried interchanging the lines. it works fine when I first instantiate the object and then append it to the list :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the object a variable references to doesn't change the value of the previous object it referenced.

So when you're doing:

```py
nick_name = input("enter nickname of the product:")
runtime.products.append(nick_name)
nick_name = runtime(nick_name)
```

All you do is add some strings to the `runtime.products` list and then make the `nick_name` variable point to a new `runtime` object that is never used.

If you want to create a list of `runtime` objects, simply replace the lines' order:

```py
nick_name = input("enter nickname of the product:")
nick_name = runtime(nick_name)
runtime.products.append(nick_name)
```

Or simply:

```
runtime.products.append(runtime(input("enter nickname of the product:")))
```

Now you create a `runtime` object, and then add it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

It´s neccesary two modifications. 
First. On the create operation modify the order of the append

```
 nick_name = input("enter nickname of the product:")
 nick_name = runtime(nick_name)
 runtime.products.append(nick_name)
```

Second. The sense of the View operation (`int(operation) == 2`) is get the name of a class, for this is neccesary to add the class that you want to select. 
For this add:

```
    number_product = input("enter number of the product:")
```

The class modified is:

```
class runtime:
    products = []
    number_of_objects = 0
    max_objects = 10

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(self.name)
        runtime.number_of_objects += 1

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def list_of_products(cls):
        for j, i in enumerate(cls.products):
            print(j, i)

while True:
    print("1 create")
    print("2 view")
    print("3 delete")

    operation = input("enter your choice:")

    if int(operation) == 1:
        nick_name = input("enter nickname of the product:")
        nick_name = runtime(nick_name)
        runtime.products.append(nick_name)


    elif int(operation) == 2:
        runtime.list_of_products()
        number_product = input("enter number of the product:")
        print(runtime.products[int(number_product)].get_name())

    elif int(operation) == 3:
        pass

    else:
        print("choice unknown")
```